# "Scrape" meaning?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Bottlenecked by the effort of collecting data and the cost of storing
>   it on tiny 20th century hard drives, last century’s datasets tended to
>   be small. It was hard to **scrape** together enough data for even a single
>   respectable dataset, which meant that data-splitting was rarely an
>   option. This forced professionals into a choice between two
>   dramatically different mindsets.

Source : https://towardsdatascience.com/can-analysts-and-statisticians-get-along-5c9a65c8d056

What does "scrape" mean in this context? There are many definition of it.

Comment: It's a metaphorical usage; the image is of someone gathering together a small quantity of, for example, grain by scraping the ground or the bottom of a container. There wasn't much data and it was collected with difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

**Data scraping** is a technique in which a computer program extracts data from human-readable output coming from another program

[Wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_scraping)

Answer (score 1):

The verb is [**scrape together**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Scrape+together):

> **scrape together** or **scrape up**
>   *vb*
>     (*tr, adverb*) to collect with difficulty: *to scrape together money for a new car*.